# Whole output is not displaying in the content-header, when I send a http request to chatgpt api in nestjs app

Tags: rest, http, model-view-controller, nestjs, backend

generateResponse method: Integrated a chatgpt api with my nest js application, and I have created a generateResponse method which is responsible for displaying the content generated by chatgpt. The method is working fine, but it does not display everything that is generated by chatgpt, for example, when there is some code block, which is not a text/string, it would stop right there. Otherwise, it is working fine. What I want is that the content header also takes those code-blocks into consideration and displays the whole output displayed by chatgpt. Here is my chatgpt.service.ts file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import axios from 'axios';

@Injectable()
export class ChatgptService {

    private readonly api_key = "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";
   
    
      async generateChatResponse(prompt: string): Promise<string> {
        console.log("Api-key", this.api_key);
        const apiUrl = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';
        const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.api_key}`,
        };

        const requestBody = {
        messages: [{ role: 'system', content: 'You are a helpful assistant.' }, { role: 'user', content: prompt }],
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        };

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(apiUrl, requestBody, { headers });
            const fullResponse = response.data.choices[0].message.content;
            //console.dir(response.data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2))

            return fullResponse;
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.response) {
            console.error('API Response Status:', error.response.status);
            console.error('API Response Data:', error.response.data);
            } else {
            console.error('Error:', error.message);
            }
            throw new Error('Failed to generate chat response.');
        }
  
    }

    

}
```

Maybe using image, it would be easier to understand.
[image: Chatgpt Response]
So the generateChatResponse method stops when it recieves something that is not text, like in the above image, stops at makefile block.

Any help would mean a lot.